# How to remember ssh password with lsyncd?

Tags: ssh, rsync, sftp

I' m using lsyncd to sync a folder between local and remote machines with `default.rsyncssh` config. But it asks for password every time file changes.  I found there' s an option `password_file`, but using it causes the daemon exist giving no message. How to remember ssh password with lsyncd? Or is there any cross-platform GUI that can be easily configured to sync file/folder through ssh? I like the sync GUI of [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) very much, but it is paid and only on OS X.

Comment: You need to provide more information for me to be able properly answer this question. What is the OS of the local and remote machines? How many are you syncing with? What is your current lsyncd config file. Without more information all I can say is take a look at this page for a better idea to fix your problem, I think your biggest issue is you didn't set up any ssh-keys: `http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/install-and-configure-lsyncd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try authenticating with an ssh key.  Any program using ssh for the transfer will automatically find the key and not need a password.

Simply run

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then append your new `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` onto the remote side's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file

```
ssh USER@REMOTE_HOST 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

and now you should be able to ssh to the remote host without a password.

This is generally a better idea than storing your password in a file, since you might be using that password other places and if someone found it, you'd have multiple things compromised.